# Counting number of unique rows that have repeated records in one column

Tags: r

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
a <- c(1,1,4,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,3,5)
c <- c(1,4,4,4,5)
d <- c(2,2,4,4,5)
e <- c(1,5,3,3,5)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I'd like to write something that returns all unique instances of vectors a,b,c,d that have a repeated value in vector e.

For example:

```
  a b c d e 
1 1 1 1 2 1 
2 1 2 4 2 5 
3 4 3 4 4 3 
4 4 3 4 4 3 
5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Rows 3 and 4 are exactly the same till vector d (having a combination of 4344) so only one instance of those should be returned, but they have 2 repeated values in vector e. I would want to get a count on those - so the combination of 4344 has 2 repeated values in vector e.

The expected output would me how many times a certain combination such as 4344 had repeated values in vector e. So in this case it would be something like:

```
a b c d   e
4 3 4 4   2
```

Both R and SQL work, whatever does the job.

Comment: If you are going to give a negative vote, feedback would be useful

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you are going to have the SQL tag, then you should have the table structure.

Comment: Ah! Yes. I should do that. I'll take off the tag while I create a SQL table for the example

Comment: It will probably be easier for others to help if you show us your expected output for a given example.

Comment: Will do that right now @JasonAizkalns

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I would guess it is because you have two language tags on the question and zero code showing you attempted to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I added an expected output! Please let me know if it makes more sense

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you for your feedback. I did attempt to solve the problem myself and I tried so many things that I don't even know what I would put! A lot of the code I wrote were a bunch of embedded loops that took me nowhere.

Comment: I'm not really following quite what you're trying to do, but it seems like the `unique` and `aggregate` functions might be helpful to you.

Comment: I agree with @giraffehere you probably want to delete this question and repost with a clarified objective. When I say, expected output, I am inferring that you should include the *entire* expected output for the sample data. In addition, simple things like including the `data.frame` may give you more traction -- that is, `df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns thanks - I forgot to include the data.frame code. Also, that is all the expected output for the sample data. It is a difficult problem, thus difficult to understand and explain! I'm not sure how I would repost this in a better way. I think I might separate it in two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, see my comments above, but I believe the following gives you a start on your first question. First, create a "key" variable (in this case named `key_abcd` which uses `tidyr::unite` to `unite` columns `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`). Then, count up `e` by this `key_abcd` variable. The `group_by` is implicit.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

df %>%
  unite(key_abcd, a, b, c, d) %>%
  count(key_abcd, e)

#   key_abcd     e     n
#      (chr) (dbl) (int)
# 1  1_1_1_2     1     1
# 2  1_2_4_2     5     1
# 3  4_3_4_4     3     2
# 4  5_5_5_5     5     1
```

It appears from how you've worded the question, you are only interested in "more than one" combinations, therefore, you could add `%>% filter(n > 1)` to the above code.

Comment: also would you mind explaining what %>% exactly means?

Comment: I would ask "Part II" as a separate question and remove all references to it form your original question. In addition, I would expand your sample data to include more than one passing/failing case. The `%>%` is a forward-pipe operator that allows you to chain together multiple operations. See `?"%>%"` or look at the some of the vignettes in `dplyr` or lookup the `magrittr` package. The long and short: `x %>% f(y)` turns into `f(x,y)`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Edited my post and will follow your advice.